# How to send a command to container to change a file without running the container?

Tags: linux, bash, docker, shell, containers

I have a container `Postgres` that in its Dockerfile it launches a `docker-entrypoint.sh` and inside that shell file there is a command that I want to remove using this command:

```
sed -i 's/exec "$@"//g' docker-entrypoint.sh
```

The goal is to be able to run the container with the modified docker-entrypoint.sh (without the exec "@")

How can I run the container with that command launched before?
I have used another method where I override the docker-entrypoint.sh with another shell file without the 'exec "@"' and then I mount it to run my container using this command:

```
docker run -v $(pwd):/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password \
     --entrypoint="docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/docker-entrypoint-custom.sh" postgres postgres
```

I am sure there is a better way where I run a command before in bash and then run my own command

I was trying something like this but it's not working:

```
docker run --rm -v $PWD:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password  --entrypoint=/bin/bash postgres sed -i 's/exec "$@"//g' docker-entrypoint.sh &&  postgres docker-entrypoint.sh
```

Comment: The method you're using currently is the best out of the options here iMO.

Comment: you are using single quotes with `sed` command and using `$@` variable inside the it. Note that, any variable within single quote will not get interpolated. Please use double quotes.

Comment: @P.... `exec "$@"` is probably what OP wants to replace, i.e. as is, without any substitution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have used another method where I override the docker-entrypoint.sh with another shell file without the 'exec "@"'

Well, you are mounting a whole directory and you have a copy of that entrypoint. Just mount a file, and do the modifications inside your file.

```
# docker-entrypoint-custom.sh
#!/bin/sh
# do the modification
sed -i 's/exec "$@"//g' /docker-entrypoint.sh
# Just run it
/docker-entrypoint.sh "$@"
```

```
$ docker run --rm \
       -v $PWD/docker-entrypoint-custom.sh:/docker-entrypoint-custom.sh:ro \
       -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password \
       --entrypoint=/docker-entrypoint-custom.sh \
       postgres postgres
```

Another way would be to build another container with modified entrypoint instead.

```
# Dockefile....
FROM postgres
RUN sed -i 's/exec "$@"//g' /docker-entrypoint.sh
```

Comment: this is so clean! thank you it has worked!

Answer (score 1):

The default thing the `postgres` image does is to run `postgres`.  If you want it to run some other command instead, just put that command at the end of your `docker run` command.  Don't worry about editing the entrypoint script.

For debugging purposes, a very typical thing to want to do is to launch an interactive shell instead of the normal server process; then you can look around at the created filesystem and see what happened.

```
docker run --rm -it \
  -v $PWD:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d \
  -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password \
  postgres \
  /bin/bash
```

What's actually going on here?  If you look at [the image's Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/7bd41786539082857396f4d1b4f1cb326ebee8de/13/Dockerfile) you'll notice it contains both an `ENTRYPOINT` and a `CMD`:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["postgres"]
```

When you have both things, [the `CMD` is passed as additional arguments to the `ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact).  The `exec "$@"` line replaces the entrypoint script with another command that's make up of the positional parameters; that is, it replaces `docker-entrypoint.sh` with `postgres`.  It's easy to override `CMD` at the command line, as I've done above, but trickier to replace `ENTRYPOINT`.

This makes there be a generic pattern of using `ENTRYPOINT` to do first-time initialization, and then using `exec "$@"` to run the `CMD`.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# I am docker-entrypoint.sh
# Invoke me in a Dockerfile as (must use JSON-array syntax)
#   ENTRYPOINT ["/path/to/entrypoint.sh"]

# Do startup-time initialization, like creating a database or
# setting environment variables for the main process
...

# Then launch the CMD
exec "$@"
```

Comment: thank you for all your explications @David but my goal is to remove the "exec "@" " from my main shell file!

Comment: What will you do once you have that?  If you just want the container to set up the initial database in a volume and run the initialization scripts, you could make the command be something like `/bin/true`, which would have the same end effect as deleting the line.

Comment: The goal is to use this container to run a test of the schema.. /bin/true would replace the /bin/sh you mean? ( i don't know about that)

Comment: If you `docker run ... postgres /bin/true` it will launch the entrypoint script.  When it gets to the end, `exec "$@"` will run the `/bin/true` command instead of launching the database; that just exits immediately with status code 0 (success) and cause the container to stop.